# Altering Date Format in References

Tags: biblatex

I am still working on formatting my references according to my department’s standard. I am currently trying to alter a date format but failing.

I need:

```
30. Sept. 2003.
```

Yet anything I do doesn’t seem to have any influence. Find attached a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
     \addbibresource{Merkliste.bib}
     \renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
     \renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
    \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
     \renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{incollection}{\addperiod\addspace}{\addcolon\addspace}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [online]
  {url}{{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [online]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\xpatchbibmacro{title}{\printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
{\printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}\ifentrytype{online}{\addperiod}{}}%
{}{}%
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
%% Here are my tries.
\xpatchbibmacro{url+urldate}{\printfield{urlyear}\mkbibmonth{\thefield{urlmonth}}{\thefield{urlday}}}{}{}
    \xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{title}{\printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
{\printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}\ifentrytype{article}{\addperiod}{}}%
{}{}%

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}} % clears language
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}}    % clears notes
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{series}}   % clears Series
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{book}{\clearfield{number}}{}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{book}{\clearfield{pages}}{}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and a .bib-extract:

```
![@online{secretariat_a_la_politique_linguistique_quebec_dynamique_2014,
    Author = {{Secr{\'e}tariat {\`a} la politique linguistique Qu{\'e}bec}},
    Date-Modified = {2014-08-03 17:01:54 +0000},
    File = {Dynamique des langues en quelques chiffres \: Tableaux - Secr{\'e}tariat {\`a} la politique linguistique.pdf:/Users/Moritz/Desktop/Dynamique des langues en quelques chiffres \: Tableaux - Secr{\'e}tariat {\`a} la politique linguistique.pdf:application/pdf},
    Month = jul,
    Title = {La dynamique des langues en quelques chiffres : Tableaux},
    Urldate = {2014-07-28},
    Year = {2014}}][1]
```

[image: Here’s my not-perfect output]

Comment: Is there really a dot after `30`?

Comment: Yes, I just double-checked.

Comment: Strange… Never seen that. Btw, do you know that if you use biber, your .bib file can be utf8-encoded, i.e. you can type `Québec`, for instance (comment aside, I suppose it's `du` Québec).

Comment: Is the urldate field supposed to be printed in long French format, with `mainlanguage=british`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Biblatex offers different options to format a date. If the format is not a predefined one, it is possible to use `\DeclareFieldFormat` to provide a now format, in this case we can provide a format for `urldate`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  \thefield{urlday}\adddot\addspace%
  \mkbibmonth{\thefield{urlmonth}}\adddot\addspace%
  \thefield{urlyear}\isdot}
```

To use the abbreviated version for the month one can use the `dateabbrev` option of `biblatex`.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the braces are correctly placed.

Comment: There can’t be much that can’t be changed in LaTeX with tex.sx’s help:)

Comment: This disables the `urldate=` option and all other date features of `biblatex`. A different solution, while longer, is definitely preferable in general (and also in this particular case).

Comment: @moewe what is the preferred solution here ?

Comment: @baxx Depends on the details of the case. It would probably look like Paul Langeslag's answer.

Answer (score 5):

`biblatex` uses more than one date field. We'll want to reformat the output of the `date` field as well as `urldate`, for instance. Fortunately, `biblatex` calls all these date fields through `\mkbibdatelong` or `\mkbibdateshort`, so that's what we'll want to look at. We'll also need to count with the possibility that a `date` field contains only a year, say, or a date range like `1986/1990`, so we need to make use of if-then constructions.

Since the document language is set to British English, we'll want to base ourselves on `british.lbx`. It contains the following definition:

```
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
```

We need to copy this into our preamble, containing it in the argument of `\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}` and:

1. Tell `biblatex` that we want to use a longer date format using the option `alldates=long`;
2. Tell `biblatex` to abbreviate month names using the option `dateabbrev=true`;
3. Remove the alphabetical ordinal in the day field (`\mkbibordinal`);
4. Restore the `\stripzeros` that was previously triggered by the command `\mkbibordinal`;
5. Insert our punctuated ordinal with `\adddot`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,autolang=hyphen,alldates=long,dateabbrev=true]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{Merkliste.bib}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
    \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You'll find that "July" in your sample bibliography is not abbreviated because four-letter months are conventionally not abbreviated.