# biblatex change change format of urldate

Tags: biblatex

I would like to change format of URLDATE attribute.

Currently, this is what I have:

`(Accessed: 11/10/2016)`

I would like to have it like this:

`(Accessed: 11 November 2016)`

How is it possible to do?

I have searched over off. guidance of the biblatex - http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf, however none of the parameters below have helped me.

`<datetype>date=year, short, long, terse, comp, ymd, edtf 
     default: comp
     Similar to the date option but controls the format of the <datetype>date field in the datamodel`

I mean, yeah, `long` give me something like `(Accessed: Nov. 10, 2016)`, but this is not exactly, what I want. It would be nice to change month and day and make month display as the full name (eg. November).

Btw, forcing to use specific date, such as `urldate = {{date}}` does not work. Give me an error and accesses label is not even displayed in the reference.

P.s. I use Sharelatex

Answer (score 4):

Change `Nov. 10, 2016` to `November 10, 2016` by entering the following parameter: `dateabbrev=false`.

Next change `\usepackage[english]{babel}` to `\usepackage[british,english]{babel}` this will change month and day in places

and then use the following:

`\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  (Accessed: \thefield{urlday}\addspace%
  \mkbibmonth{\thefield{urlmonth}}\addspace%
  \thefield{urlyear}\isdot)}`

to specify any custom layout of accessed date.

Source of prev. code: from this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194594/112462

Comment: For a conceptually nicer (but very possibly longer) solution you'd simply adapt the language-dependent date macros in your `.lbx` file. See [Formatting dates “day month year” with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129170/35864) and [DMY date and serial comma with Biblatex-chicago](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141355/35864) for example. With `biblatex` >= 3.6 your mileage may vary, the code might have to be adapted a bit.