# biblatex change format of urldate

Tags: biblatex, formatting

How to get a comma after the day in „urldate“: Accessed December 08, 2016

I recognized [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333780/biblatex-change-change-format-of-urldate), it helped me forward but did not solve my problem.

`\thefield{urlday}\iscomma \addspace` does not work
neither does `\mkbibday{\thefield{urlday}\iscomma}\addspace`

```
\documentclass[version=last,11pt,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[babel,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[backend=biber,babel=other,style=nejm,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[backend=biber,babel=other,style=myStile,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
    (Accessed%
    \mkbibmonth{\thefield{urlmonth}}\addspace%
    \thefield{urlday}\addspace%
    %\thefield{urlday}\iscomma \addspace% does not work
    %\mkbibday{\thefield{urlday}\iscomma}% does not work
    \thefield{urlyear}\isdot)}

\addbibresource{testBiblio.bib}

\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{english}

    \begin{filecontents}{testBiblio.bib}
    @Conference{AuthorMAuthorN2016,
        author      = {Author, M and Author, N},
        title       = {{{T}he {T}itle}},
        subtitle    = {{{T}he {S}ubtitle}},
        titleaddon  = {[abstract]},
        number      = {no pagination},
        eventtitle  = {{A}nnual {C}onf},
        urldate     = {2016-12-08},
        url         = {http://nothing.org/of/interest/},
        series      = {11 (suppl 12)},
        eventdate   = {2016}
    }
    \end{filecontents}

    \section{foo}

    Part of a proceeding \cite{AuthorMAuthorN2016} \\

    \printbibliography[title={References}]
\end{document}
```

[nejm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco-daniel) is according to AMA, it is a derivative of „numeric-icomp“.

I already created the files `/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg`,  `/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/myStile.bbx` and `/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/myStile.cbx` with dummy-text: `\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg} \endinput bzw`. `\ProvidesFile{myStyle.bbx} \RequireBibliographyStyle{nejm} \endinput` and `\ProvidesFile{myStile.cbx} \RequireBibliographyStyle{nejm} \endinput`, an ran `'texhash TEXMFHOME'` but I don‘t know what to put into `*.cfg` or `*.bbx`.

I use TeX Live 2015.20160320-1 and compile with XeLaTeX on Xubuntu 1604

Answer (score 2):

`biblatex-nejm` uses a slightly unusual way of getting only the year. Try the following

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}
         {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}
     {\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{,\space}}%
     \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}
         {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}
         {/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
     \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
```

And load `biblatex` with the options `alldates=year,urldate=long`.

```
\documentclass[version=last,11pt,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[babel,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,babel=other,style=nejm,dateabbrev=false,alldates=year,urldate=long]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@conference{AuthorMAuthorN2016,
  author      = {Author, M and Author, N},
  title       = {{{T}he {T}itle}},
  subtitle    = {{{T}he {S}ubtitle}},
  titleaddon  = {[abstract]},
  number      = {no pagination},
  eventtitle  = {{A}nnual {C}onf},
  urldate     = {2016-12-08},
  url         = {http://nothing.org/of/interest/},
  series      = {11 (suppl 12)},
  eventdate   = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}
         {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}
     {\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{,\space}}%
     \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}
         {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}
         {/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
     \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
  Part of a proceeding \cite{AuthorMAuthorN2016}
  \printbibliography[title={References}]
\end{document}
```

Gives

> Author, M and Author, N. The Title. The Subtitle. [abstract]. In: Annual Conf. (2016). 11 (suppl 12) no pagination. url: http://nothing.org/of/interest/ (visited on December 8, 2016).

Comment: thank you so much for `mk...zeros` commands.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194575/altering-date-format-in-references/194594#194594), an now it works:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
    (Accessed %
    \mkbibmonth{\thefield{urlmonth}}\addspace%
    \thefield{urlday}\addcomma \addspace     %  addcomma works !!!
    \thefield{urlyear}\isdot)}
```

Comment: This is generally not a good idea because it hard-codes text (which would better be solved with bibstrings) and hard-codes a primitive date format that completely disables all of `biblatex`'s date formatting options for this date.